# Sort javascript Array in a pre-defined order

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have a JavaScript array that I need to sort in a pre-defined order. It seems random, but they do need to be in a specific order.

Here is where I started, but am not sure how to finish:

```
// Items
var items = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Grapes", "Peaches", "Bananas", "Watermelon"];
var itemsOrdered = {};

// Order how I want them
for (i in items) {
    var item = items[i];
    if (item == 'Apples') {
        itemsOrdered['4'] = item;
    } else if (item == 'Oranges') {
        itemsOrdered['2'] = item;
    } else if (item == 'Grapes') {
        itemsOrdered['1'] = item;
    } else if (item == 'Peaches') {
        itemsOrdered['3'] = item;
    } else if (item == 'Bananas') {
        itemsOrdered['6'] = item;
    } else if (item == 'Watermelon') {
        itemsOrdered['5'] = item;
    }
}
```

**Order should be:**

- Apples: 4
- Oranges: 2
- Grapes: 1
- Peaches: 3
- Bananas: 6
- Watermelon: 5

All of these items might not always be in the array. It might only be Apples and Bananas, but they still need the same sort positions.

I have to set this manual sort order after the array is created because our system prints them out in this random order which we then need to sort correctly.

In the end, I need the correctly sorted fruits back in an array.

Ideas?

Comment: How do you want them sorted? Can you show us which order?

Comment: It is there under the "Order how I want them" section.

Comment: What do you want at position `0`? Why are you using an object instead of an array?

Comment: What is the logic behind such sorting? You can't make an "I-Want-It-Like-That" algorithm.

Comment: where are you stuck ?

Comment: The logic? A client needs them in a specific order for a project.

Comment: Generally speaking, I would use int types for the indexing here instead of making it a string number. Other than that though, what isn't working about your current code?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try:

```
var items = ["Apples", "Bananas", "Watermelons"];
var itemsOrdered = [];
var theOrder = ["Grapes", "Oranges", "Peaches", "Apples", "Watermelons", "Bananas"];

for (var i = 0; i < theOrder.length; i++) {
    if (items.indexOf(theOrder[i]) > -1) {
        itemsOrdered.push(theOrder[i]);
    }
}

console.log(itemsOrdered);
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/JPNGS/

The order is defined in `theOrder`. `items` contains the available items. `itemsOrdered` contains the available items, ordered.

Comment: Not sure how well this scales ... what if `theOrder` had 100 or 1000 elements and `items` only had 10 ?

Answer (score 13):

Put your ordering in an object, like this:

```
var ordering = {};
ordering["Apples"] = 4;
ordering["Oranges"] = 2;
... // etc.
```

Then sort your `items` array using `Array.sort(compareFunction(a, b))`, passing it a sorting function to check your objects against `ordering` (left as an exercise). Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort to see how `compareFunction()` is used.

Edit: Here's an implementation:

```
var ordering = {"Apples":4, "Oranges":2, "Grapes":1, 
                "Peaches":3, "Bananas":6, "Watermelons":5};
var items = ["Apples", "Oranges", "Grapes", 
             "Peaches", "Bananas", "Watermelons"];
items.sort(function(a,b) { return ordering[a] - ordering[b]; })
> ["Grapes", "Oranges", "Peaches", "Apples", "Watermelons", "Bananas"]
```

Comment: You are defining an object, not an array.

Comment: True. I was thinking more of a hash. A plain object works fine, though. Edited.

Comment: You could now use a Map instead of a plain Object for the ordering.

Answer (score 0):

First convert your object to an Array:

```
var sortOrder = [];

for (i in itemsOrdered)
    sortOrder[i-1] = itemsOrdered[i];
```

Then use `.filter()` like this:

```
var result = sortOrder.filter(item) {
    return items.indexOf(item) !== -1;
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Your code simplifies to:

```
var itemsOrdered = {1:"Peaches",2:"Oranges",3:"Grapes",4:"Apples",5:"Watermelon",6:"Bananas"};
```

In other words, it's completely pointless. Just define them in the order you want them.

Comment: I have to set this manual sort order after the array is created because our system prints them out in this random order which we then need to sort correctly.